# Column Name in the CSV file after converting from JSON using JQ

Tags: json, header, export-to-csv, jq

I am having problems on adding a column on my csv.

```
$ jq -r '.cveRules[] | [.effect, .id, .description, .expiration.date] | @csv' vulexemptioncmndt.json
"ignore","CVE-2020-8116","Package dot-prop 4.2.0, status: fixed in 5.1.1, 4.2.1","2021-02-27T23:00:00Z"
"ignore","CVE-2020-8252","Package node 10.21.0, status: fixed in 14.9.0, 12.18.4, 10.22.1","2021-02-27T23:00:00Z"
"ignore","CVE-2020-8265","Package node 10.21.0, status: fixed in 10.23.1","2021-02-27T23:00:00Z"
```

What commands should I add so I can have a result of

```
"Effect", "ID", "Description", "Expiration Date"
"ignore","CVE-2020-8116","Package dot-prop 4.2.0, status: fixed in 5.1.1, 4.2.1","2021-02-27T23:00:00Z"
"ignore","CVE-2020-8252","Package node 10.21.0, status: fixed in 14.9.0, 12.18.4, 10.22.1","2021-02-27T23:00:00Z"
"ignore","CVE-2020-8265","Package node 10.21.0, status: fixed in 10.23.1","2021-02-27T23:00:00Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the header row being treated like any other CSV row, a jq-only solution would be to add an array of the desired header names to your filter like so:

```
["Effect", "ID", "Description", "Expiration Date"],
(.cveRules[] | [.effect, .id, .description, .expiration.date])
| @csv
```

If you want more control of the header row, then prepend your filter with the desired header row as a single string.