# JQ Add (static) header before filter

Tags: json, jq

Consider the following (simplified) JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "type": "foo",
        "name": "test_1"
    },
    {
        "type": "bar",
        "name": "test_2"
    },
    {
        "type": "bar",
        "name": "test_3"
    }
]
```

---

I'm using the following filter to generate my output:

```
group_by(.type)[][] | "\(if "type" == "foo" then "oof" else "rab" end)&\(.name)"
```

This produces

```
rab&test_2
rab&test_3
rab&test_1
```

<sup>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5EswrYDxhW)</sup>

Using `column -ts '&'` this gets converted to:

```
rab  test_2
rab  test_3
rab  test_1
```

---

My *problem*; I need to add a custom header line, so that the output becomes:

```json
test&foo&bar
rab&test_2
rab&test_3
rab&test_1
```

---

There are many questions how to add (a static) set of header lines, like:

- [How to add a header to CSV export in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015555/how-to-add-a-header-to-csv-export-in-jq)
- [Column Name in the CSV file after converting from JSON using JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897260/column-name-in-the-csv-file-after-converting-from-json-using-jq)

But I'm unable to combine it so I can leave the `group_by` intact and let `column` handle the spacing

(I'd rather let `column` handle the spacing)

---

<sup>***tl;dr***;</sup>
How can I add a custom header array, something like:

```
[ "test", "foo", "bar" ] | join("&")
```

So that

- The `group_by` and everything behind it isn't changed
- `column` can parse the output

---

**Edit**, of course I can pull off the `column` from the `jq` command, and 'abuse' `echo` like so:

```sh
ugly=$(curl --silent <URI> \
        | jq -r 'group_by(.type)[][] | "\(if "type" == "foo" then "oof" else "rab" end)&\(.name)"' \
        | egrep --color -E "FooBar|$")
headers="foo#bar#foorbar"
echo "$headers\n$ugly" | column -ts '#' \
```

But I'd rather keep the `| column` on the `jq` part so that `echo` and `$ugly` aren't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your expression in brackets and add `| ["test&foo&bar"] + . | .[]` at the end.

```
[group_by(.type)[][] | "\(if "type" == "foo" then "oof" else "rab" end)&\(.name)"] | ["test&foo&bar"] + . | .[]
```

Not sure why you need `columns`. Seems like you can just replace `&` with `\t`.

Comment: Many thanks, didn't expect it to be so easy. I'd need `columns` because not each column is one `\t` width. So using `\t` will misalign the output, `column` can handle that as expected.

Comment: Not sure why you need two filters at the end : `| "test&foo&bar",.[]`